# сортировка по 2 спискaм в python

Tags: python, python-2.x, списки

Допустим есть два списка:

```
a=["Andrei","Oleg","Vadim","Vladimir"]  
b=[4,2,1,3]
```

Не могу понять как сделать сортировку по списку `b`, чтобы соответственно расположить имена в списке `а`, и в итоге получилось:

```
a=["Vadim","Oleg","Vladimir","Andrei"]  
b=[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: сделать функцию с сортировкой и загнать туда по очередно два массива

Comment: Испульзуйте hashmap

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, есть вариант сделать так:

```
a=["Andrei","Oleg","Vadim","Vladimir"]
b=[4,2,1,3]
a.sort()
b.sort()
```

Comment: Это просто сортировка двух списков по отдельности. Автор как будто бы хочет отсортировать их как кортежи по второму элементу.

Answer (score 1):

```
[z[1] for z in sorted(zip(b, a))]
```